# How to dockerize a springboot application that connects with AWS RDS Postgres instance?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker

[image: Application Architecture]

In application.properties I have provided with the instance details of my instance.

[image]

Every time I try to run docker-compose up, it gives following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5433 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:303) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar!/:42.2.18]
```

I haven't specified localhost and port 5433 anywhere in code, properties or any other configurations.

It seems that the dockerized code is not able connect with the AWS instance, where as if I run this application on local without docker it works completely fine.
Does the docker-compose require any configurations or network related settings?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Answer (score 4):

If you look at your screenshot you will see you are still trying to connect to your database at localhost.  Your properties are not being properly loaded.

Comment: I don't have any configurations with localhost.

Comment: Your own application disagrees with you. The port 5433 is not the standard postgres port so it must be coming from somewhere.

Comment: my friend it also does not contain any such port in the configurations.